# How can I set a secure flag on cookies generated from a Python application?

Tags: https, apache2, cookie

I have an application written in Python running behind Apache and SSL. I am not seeing a secure flag on my cookie:

`apache Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)`

I have added a configuration line to my *ssl.conf* as:

`Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;Secure;HttpOnly`

I don't have enough points to post a screen shot of my session. Can anyone share their experience with this or provide any help?

Comment: So far I didn't find a way to configure secure flag to cookie through apache. Instead a I wrote a small python function to set the secure flag.